# Why does innodb buffer pool memory grow after command "optimize table"?

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-indexes

I use docker on local machine with Mysql container.

Steps:

1. Launch mysql docker. Uses memory about 2-2.5G.
2. Launch command "optimize table". Uses memory grow up to 4.5-5G;
3. Restart mysql docker and uses memory 2-2.5G again (see screenshot)
4. List item;

Database has 10 small tables (< 10 rows) and one huge table (10,000,000 rows with 10 columns, table has index for every column).

Why it happens?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVQtB.png)

Comment: *"Why it happens?"* Do you want to short answer or the long one? Because most likely the long answer will be to large to explain here.

Comment: The short one is. Most likely `optmize table` uses the innodb buffer pool to make it possible to do faster rebuilds off the table and index.. Because it's faster in thoery to load the table data or part off it in memory and rebuild the pages from the memory then doing multiple random disk I/O to get the pages from disk and doing the rebuild.

Comment: I thought all tables in memory also, because InnoDB Buffer Pool Data set to 8G.
Or I unsertand something wrong?

Comment: InnoDB does not automatic load tables in memory read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB tables.  It almost never provides any benefit.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` copies the table over.  Apparently you have `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`, which implies that it will make a second copy of the table in `ibdata1`.
- "An index for every column" -- This is usually a waste.  Look at the `SELECTs` ou have to see what indexes you can use.  (Ask for help here, but provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the relevant queries.)
- The buffer_pool is in RAM; its size is limited by `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  When MySQL starts (in your Docker, for example), it will start out small and grow, perhaps up to that size.
- Doing the `OPTIMIZE`, especially with so many indexes, will consume some or all of the available buffer_pool.